# Java - MousePress Hold and Release event listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

hello is there a way mouse even that can Hold the mouse and release cause I can't find it on google.

so for example this image..

When the `jTextBox` is `****` when he click the button, he see the words `oops`...
then after he release the click of mouse the `jTextBox` will back to `****` again

I know this code already but the mouseevent is I only don't know

[image]

Comment: just implement `java.awt.event.MouseListener` and add it to your button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will want to implement the `MouseListener` interface with a new class and add this new `Listener` against your button with the following;

`button.addMouseListener(new YourMouseListener());`

An example custom `MouseListener` might look like this.

```
class YourMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
          // Insert code to show password  
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         // Insert code to hide password again
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: how about I have icon and when I press the button will change and when I release it will back to normal

Comment: You should be able to do that using the above code example. Just add in the code to change the button's icon in the `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()` methods. If that's what your asking. Giving example code to change the button's icon however, is probably beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a Robot object. This can do things as follows:

```
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

The Mousebutton is pressed until you do this:

```
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

This should do what you want.